# Raspberry pi python divide produces integer

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, divide

I hope you can help me.  I am coding in python on a Raspberry Pi, I use pycharm to draft the code then copy across.  I am trying to count from 1.00 to 2.00 in 0.01 steps.  This is my code:

```
import time
import os

try:
    pause = 0.1
    while (True):
        for i in range(100, 201, 1):
            i /= 100
            print(str(i))
            time.sleep(pause)

except (KeyboardInterrupt):
    os.system('clear')
    print("Complete")
```

In pycharm it gives an expected response of

> 1.01,
>   1.02,
>   1.03...

On the RPi this gives:

> 1, 1,
>   1...

Any idea why?  I'm tearing my hair out.

Comment: You're probably running a version of python that doesn't do float division by default - try adding `from __future__ import division` to the beginning of your python script

Comment: See [PEP 238 -- Changing the Division Operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both environments are probably using different versions of Python.

Integer division on Python3 returns a float, whereas integer division in Python2 will return an integer.

Cast you denominator to float so that it is an integer / float division and returns a float in both Python versions:

```
i /= 100.0
```

Comment: This sorted it.  Thanks!! Everyday is a school day!  I really need to get to grips with the fundamental differences.